# Convert all font-size and line height in px to em from css file

Tags: jquery, css, html, sass, sublimetext2

I have a CSS file, in this we have used `px` for units. Due to change in our project scope we need to make site responsive on mobile devices so we are supposed to convert `font-size` and `line-height` to `em` which we are doing manually right now.

Are there any sublime plugins or any other tools that converts only `font-size` and `line-height` to `em` excluding things like `padding`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but you could use a RegEx find-replace. But this doesn't take into account size variation. You could use `rem-calc()` and assuming that your CSS is well formatted, you could do something like this:

Find:

```
(font-size: )(\d+(.\d+)?)px
```

Replace:

```
${1}rem-calc(${2})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
var regFindPX = new RegExp('(\\d+)px','g');
var reg3decPoints = new RegExp('(\.\\d{3}).*', '');

var css = 'css code';
var result;
while ((result = regFindPX.exec(css)) !== null) {
    var px = parseInt(result[1]);
    var em = px / 16;
    em = em.toString().replace(reg3decPoints, '$1');
    css = css.replace(px + 'px', em + 'em'); 

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with PostCss (https://github.com/postcss/postcss ) you could take advantage of some plugins like https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-px-to-em or https://github.com/cuth/postcss-pxtorem